# How to prove that composition of two hyperbolic isometries is a hyperbolic isometry

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis

I know that trace is > 2 for hyperbolic isometry and composition of two isometries is an isometry. But I can't figure out how to actually prove this. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: @Lays - right, that's where I got the two isometries is an isometry. I'm confused as if that proof works for my question ?

Comment: Sry, I should have read your question better.

Comment: This is not strictly true if you define the identity to not be a hyperbolic isometry.

Comment: @DanielRust- What's not strictly true ?

Comment: If the set of hyperbolic isometries does not include the identity, then, if $\gamma$ is hyperbolic, so is its inverse $\gamma^{-1}$, however $\gamma\circ\gamma^{-1}=\mbox{Id}_H$ which is not hyperbolic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show that the composition of 2 isometries is an isometry, you could just show that $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is closed under multiplication.

If you wanted to prove that the composition of two hyperbolic isometries is hyperbolic, well you would be unable to because it's not true.  And it's not just a matter of ruling out the trivial case pointed out by Daniel Rust (though that is the easiest way of proving it).  From a geometric standpoint, it is possible to compose two dilations having different fixed points and get something that's not a dilation.  From an algebraic standpoint, you can come up with many examples of two matrices in $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ with real trace greater than 2, that when multiplied yield a matrix with real trace less than or equal to 2.  Here is just one:
$\begin{pmatrix}
2 \ 0\\
0 \ \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \ -7\\
3 \ 10\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-4 \ -14\\
\frac{3}{2} \ 5\\
\end{pmatrix}$.